# Sampling from either a known or unknown Gaussian

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

Suppose I have two Gaussian distributions $N(\mu_0, \sigma), N(\mu_1, \sigma)$ with identical variance, where $\mu_0, \sigma$ are known and $\mu_1$ is unknown. Suppose I realize a sample $x$ from one of these two distributions.

1. What can I say about the probability that $x$ is not from $N(\mu_0, \sigma)$? A reasonable thing to do would be to compute a p-value. That is, assume that $x$ does come from $N(\mu_0, \sigma)$ and then compute $P(x \leq t)$ under $N(\mu_0, \sigma)$. If this probability is sufficiently small then I can reject the thought that $x$ is sampled from $N(\mu_0, \sigma)$. Is this the only thing I can do?
2. What can I say about the probability that $x$ is sampled from $N(\mu_1, \sigma)$? My first thought is nothing, since I don't know $\mu_1$. For all I know $\mu_1 = \mu_0$. But what if I assume that $\mu_1 > \mu_0$. What can I say about the probability that $x$ is sampled from a distribution with greater mean than $\mu_0$? If I knew both means then I could compute probabilities as above for both and choose the distribution with greater probability as the one more likely to have generated $x$, but I don't know $\mu_1$.

To give some intuition about what I'm thinking about here. I could imagine sampling many times from both $N(\mu_0, \sigma), N(\mu_1, \sigma)$, and running a t-test to determine if $\mu_0 < \mu_1$. But I don't have many samples, I know $\mu_0, \sigma$, and I have a single sample $x$, and I want to know what I can say about it likely coming from a distribution with greater mean than $\mu_0$.

Comment: Solution #1 sounds reasonable.

Comment: The approach you give under item 1 answers a very different question from the one you said you wanted to answer. Looking at your words it seems you are saying you wish to compute $\frac{P(\text{Model 2}|\text{data})}{P(\text{Model 1}|\text{data})+P(\text{Model 2}|\text{data})}$ (given the data, the probability that it came from model 2 rather than model 1), but the p-value *does not give you that*. You either need to change the question you're asking (if perhaps you didn't quite ask for what you wanted) or you must strive to answer the original question, which is Bayesian in form